# VBA- Total by month, year and other fields

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA, stack overflow, and not very good with excel either, so I'm probably doomed lol.

I have  some data in excel that looks like this:

[image]

I want to loop though each record and make totals for certain combinations of criteria.

Specifically, I want to make tables for every combination of enterprise, and size by year by month.  For example, below is the table for "Mary Jane Co." when the size field is "small":

This is the table I want to populate:

[image]

Should I even be doing this in VBA? Or is it best to do it in a WS?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far...?

Comment: Hi there. You should research PivotTables, I think this is what you are after for this sort of data summary :)